# What is the correct way to push a "read-only" git submodule in a tagged repository?

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-push, git-tag

I am working on Project A, and I want to push the tagged releases from that project to GitHub. Project A depends on Project B, which is a submodule.

Project B releases an upstream update, and I want to merge that update into my project.

1. Is `git submodule update --init --merge` the correct way to merge in that update?
2. When I did `git push --tags`, it also pushed all of the submodule's tags. `git tag` also shows all of the submodule's tags instead of just the parent project's tags. How can I isolate and push only the tags from the parent project?

**edit**: it occurred to me that I might be asking the wrong question. I'm concerned that the subproject's tags will conflict with my main project's tags.

Answer (score 0):

git push is a repo-level command, so in the same way you can't select certain commits to be pushed or to not be pushed, pretty sure that you can't select which tags are/are not pushed.

Comment: Maybe this is an XY problem then. My concern is that my parent project's tags might conflict with the submodule's tags, because `git tag -l` just displays them in a jumble all together.